# ASP.Net MVC одна кнопка "сохранить"

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, visual-studio, mvc

Есть приложение с таблицей написанное на с# MVC. В стандартной реализации таблицы, допускается редактирование, удаление и обновление записей построчно.

Необходимо изменения хранить на таблице, а применять их по нажатию одной кнопки "сохранить", расположенную на таблице. Может есть какие-то готовые решения по этому поводу?

Пока рабочий вариант сохранять все изменения в local storage на JavaScript/jQuery. А на кнопку вешать обработку массивов сохранённых изменений.

Comment: Что не устраивает в текущем варианте и чего пытаетесь добиться?

Comment: хочется дать возможность пользователю отредактировать все данные, посмотреть на то, что получится, подумать и "сохранить".

Comment: То есть, вы хотите, чтобы черновик хранился локально, а после нажатия на кнопку, данные отправлялись на сервер?

Comment: совершенно верно

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать проще, без local storage и массива сохранений изменений.

1. Вариант с **MVC** .
   Необходимо использовать строго типизированное представление и можно выводить таблицу в foreach, а input связать с полями модели. Тогда при изменении значения в input изменится модель и ее можно просто сохранить. [Почитай здесь пример.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd410405(v=vs.98).aspx)
2. Вариант с **angular js**.
   Подключи к проекту angular. 
   И сделай таблицу через ng-repeat.

Ангуляр сам следит за изменением модели. Т.е. все, что ты поменяешь во view, то сразу же будет доступно в контроллере. Пример таблицы с редактированием - http://jsfiddle.net/ NfPcH/93/

Comment: вариант с angular к сожалению отпадает, т.к. уже jQuery используется в проекте.